# How to return from GetIdNumber?

Tags: c#

How to return from GetIdNumber? //How do I return something?

Im using Nhibernate in the code below so the example hard to test maybe!

You can remove if you want!

```
public class ClassID 
{
    public virtual string Idnumber { get; set; }
}

public class ClassOne
{

    public IEnumerable<string> GetMessage()
    {        
        var sendBackVariabel = Session.QueryOver<ClassID>()
                                      .WhereRestrictionOn(_ => _.Idnumber)
                                      .IsIn(GetIdNumber().ToArray())
                                      .List(); //using Nhibernate here
        return sendBackVariabel;
    }


    private ICollection<string> GetIdNumber()
    {
        //How do I return something?
    }

}
```

Comment: if you remove `//how do I` and `something?` from that line of code...

Comment: @Sayse, good one! The problem here I think comes not from the actual return, but from the use of `ICollection`.

Comment: @AndreiV I can't see why `GetIdNumber` would event want to return a collection, I've VTC as it is unclear what the op is asking about..

Comment: @Sayse, I'm assuming an unfortunate mix of auto-generated code and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Just return anything that implements ICollection, for example:

```
private ICollection<string> GetIdNumber()
{
   return new List<string> { "MyId" };
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you simplify things a bit? By looking at the question I'm assuming that he/she is a beginner. I would initialize the list before the `return` and would add items using the `Add` method. This would improve readability for beginners.

Comment: If you want you can do I an example with the Add method also :)

Comment: I added Add myself, here how I do it!


    private ICollection<string> GetIdNumber()
        {

            var parts = new List<string>();
            parts.Add("MyId");
            return parts;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what your trying to do but you should probably only return one value, your Idnumber like this:

```
private string GetIdNumber()
{
    return Idnumber;
}
```